# What is head in Linked List Java Implementation

Tags: java, linked-list, this, nodes, head

I am reading "Cracking the Coding interview" and I noticed the code below for a Linked List implementation in Java.

```
class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;

    public Node (int d){
        data = d;
    }

    void appendToTail(int d){
        Node end = new Node(d);
        Node n = this;
        while(n.next != null){
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = end;
    }
}
```

The line **Node n = this;** confuses me very much.
We are supposed to start at the head of the list and go till the end of the list.
"This" in java usually refers to the current instance.
So, how are these two related?
I'm sure I am missing something here. Please help!

Comment: `this` does indeed refer to the current instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever, for `Node` reference `someNode`, `someNode.appendToTail(x)` is called, it will create a new `Node` with data value `x`, and append it to the tail of whatever list contains `someNode`. If `someNode` is not already part of a list, it will, afterwards, be the head of a two node list with the new node as tail. If `someNode` is part of a longer list, the new node will be the tail of that list.

To do that, `appendToTail` has to find the tail note, the one with a `null` `next` pointer. It starts the search with itself, using `this`. If it is the tail of its list, the loop will be skipped because `next` is `null`, and the `n.next = end;` assignment will have the effect of `next = end;`. If there are more nodes in the list, the while loop will skip over them until it finds the current tail.

Comment: Can you explain to me why they use `this`? Does this mean that `this` implies the `head` node? That's what's been confusing to me about the CTCI solution.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage The appendToTail operation appends a Node with data `d` at the end of the list of Nodes attached to `this`. However, `this` could itself be a later node in a list with a different head.